# How to change ro.build.version.release in Android sources?

Tags: android, properties

I build custom ROM for pandaboard. I would like to change/customize `ro.build.version.release`.

1. I changed `PLATFORM_VERSION := 4.0.4.0.4.0.4` in **`build/core/version_defaults.mk`**. The build version printed when building gets updated correctly. But after reflashing the boot image, the `ro.build.version.release` in the pandaboard remained the old one.
2. I added `BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += androidbuild.version.release=4.0.4.0.19` to **`device/ti/panda/Boardconfig.mk`**, but that did not make the trick.
3. I ended up in adding `setprop ro.build.version.release 4.0.4.0.19` to **`init.omap4pandaboard.rc`** on `post-fs-data` rule, but that's definitely not clean...

Does anyone know where this android property can be changed?

Comment: I'd be glad to know what is "vague, incomplete, overly broad or rhetorical" in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad. I reflashed the **`boot`** image although ro.build.version.release seems to be in the **`system`** image. So solution 1 above was the right one...